# Extending Timeout For Request Module

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any way to extend the default timeout for the Request object in the FireFox Add-On?  On some pages, it appears that a cross site request in our extension is timing out and there is no published option associated with the Request module that allows the timeout to be extended.  The xhr object requires extended permissions so we would prefer to use the Request object exclusively if at all possible.

Also, what is the default Request timeout set to?

Comment: There is no specific timeout for the `request` module, rather lots of different timeouts for Firefox networking as a whole. Which one are you interested in, it the request failing at DNS resolution, or establishing server connection, or waiting for server response?

Comment: I believe the timeout causing the problem is "waiting for server response".  I need to know the default value and how to change it from within my addon's code.

Comment: @WladimirPalant I'd be interested in the "waiting for server response" part.

Comment: @timgeb: Usually, `network.http.response.timeout` preference applies here - that's 5 minutes by default. For SPDY connections the relevant preference should be `network.http.spdy.timeout` however (3 minutes). I guess that the same preference applies for HTTP 2.0 connections. And then there is `network.http.pipelining.read-timeout` for pipelined connections (not that anybody should still enable HTTP pipelining these days).

Answer (score 2):

With the Request module there's no way to change the default timeout.  Request uses the xhr module but doesn't give access to the timeout property.

You can see in the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#Properties) docs that the `timeout` property defaults to zero and so it should not timeout, but as Wladimir points out there are different network level timeouts that you're also running into.

If you wanted to make a pull request I'm sure the SDK team would look into accepting a timeout parameter in the Request module. e.g.

```
  get timeout() { return request(this).timeout; },
  set timeout(value) { request(this).timeout = validateSingleOption('timeout', value); },
```

*(Note that you can't extend the Request class as it's using a namespace)*

I don't think this change to the Request module will really solve your network timeout problem as it seems to be timing out at another level.